# Database (Oracle 11g) query optimization for joins

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g, query-optimization

So I am trying to optimize a bunch of queries which are taking a lot of time. What I am trying to figure out is how to create an index on columns from different tables.
Here is a simple version of my problem.

**What I did**

After Googling I looked into bitmap index but I am not sure if this is the right way to solve the issue

**Issue**

1. There is a many to many relationship b/w Student(sid,...) and Report(rid, year, isdeleted)
2. StudentReport(id, sid, rid) is the join table

**Query**

```
Select * 
from Report 
inner join StudentReport on Report.rid = StudentReport.rid
where Report.isdeleted = 0 and StudentReport.sid = x and Report.year = y
```

What is the best way to create an index?

Comment: Never try to optimize a query without a plan. Docs for [EXPLAIN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/ex_plan.htm). Paste it into your question.  If I had to guess, I'd guess that you don't have a UNIQUE constraint on {sid, rid} in the StudentReport table, and that you don't have an index on Report.Year.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I don't have access to the db right now but I will paste the query plan later. I do have a unique constraint {sid, rid} on StudentReport. I also tried adding an index (isdeleted, year) on Student. Also the above query is being run for a lot of student so its something like --> loop 1 to 1000 { execute query }

Comment: Assuming that isdeleted has only two values, and that most of the rows have False for that column, it probably won't help you much to index it. Executing queries in a loop is rarely the right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
with TMP_REP AS (
Select * from Report where Report.isdeleted = 0 AND Report.year = y
)
,TMP_ST_REP AS(
Select * 
from StudentReport where StudentReport.sid = x
)
SELECT * FROM TMP_REP R, TMP_ST_REP S WHERE S.rid = R.rid
```